# Simultaneous plots with ggplot2 according to a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here there is a "toy example" with a similar dataset I am working with.

```
Gender <- rep(c("M","F"),15)
City <- rep(rep(c("City A", "Citi B","City C"),c(2,2,2)),5)
Year   <- rep(2010:2014, c(6,6,6,6,6))
Pop <- floor(runif(30, min = 10000, max = 15000))
df <- data.frame(Gender, City, Year, Pop)
```

I have the information of the population of males and females (`Gender`) for different cities (`City`) over some years (`Year`).
I would like to get a representation of the evolution of the population for the different cities in two different plots (one for males and another one for females), using `ggplot2`.

Is it there a way to get this representation simultaneously avoiding to run two different plots? It can be hard to get this when the factor has many different levels.

Comment: yes, use facets.

Comment: Thank you @tjebo! Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, please don't delete it! Duplicate questions are good! They increase the visibility / searchability of good threads